# Reverse for 'like_majstor' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['likeProfile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$'] problem

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to add a **like** button for my users. I have two types of users in my `AbstractUser` model separated by `user_type`. And I want this behavior of **like** button: users of type `KORISNIK`, can like a user by type of `MAJSTORI`.
But when I try to run my solution I get this error:

> Reverse for 'like_majstor' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['likeProfile/(?P[0-9]+)$'] problem

models.py

```
class CustomKorisnici(AbstractUser):
    MAJSTOR = '1'
    KORISNIK = '2'
    USER_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        (MAJSTOR, 'majstor'),
        (KORISNIK, 'korisnik')
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + ' | ' +self.last_name + ' | ' + self.first_name + ' | ' + str(self.phone_number) + ' | ' + self.user_type + ' | ' + self.email+ ' | ' + str(self.id)

class LikeButton(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomKorisnici, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(CustomKorisnici,related_name='profile_like')
```

views.py

```
def LikeProfile(request,pk):
    like = get_object_or_404(LikeButton, id=request.POST.get('majstori_id'))
    like.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('majstori_profile', args=[str(pk)]))

class MajstoriProfile(DetailView):
    model = CustomKorisnici
    context_object_name = 'majstori'
    template_name = 'majstori_profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = CustomKorisnici.objects.all()
        context = super(MajstoriProfile, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        majstori= get_object_or_404(CustomKorisnici, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['majstori'] = majstori
        return context
```

urls.py

```
 path('likeProfile/<int:pk>', LikeProfile, name="like_majstor"),
```

template:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_majstor' majstor.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="majstor_id" value="{{ majstor.pk }}" class="btn">Like</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the other view which renders given template.

Comment: It should be `{% url 'like_majstor' majstori.pk %}`? notice the `i`. You have set `context_object_name = 'majstori'`.

Answer (score 0):

try in url

```
url(r'^likeProfile/(?P[0-9].+)/$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action attribute should be

```
{% url 'like_majstor' majstori.pk %}
```

Looks like you missed an 'i'.